# media3/exoplayer not fullscreen

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to create a fullscreen player using media3/exoplayer but there is a gap between the player and the screen; see image below:

[image]

This is my activity, it is simple, and it used to work three years ago, now I'm rewriting the project and facing this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:use_controller="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have this style for the application

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

What I'm doing wrong? The video is 1080p

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by removing the custom theme.